# Create child component and call function. Angular 5.2.1

Tags: angular

I have a table in a parent component that when clicking on a row, I painted a child component that was with ngIf to false until that moment.

At the moment that I want to paint the child component, call a function of the child and pass the row to it, and I do not just have to pass the data, I have to process it in the child, that's why I need to call a function

// view father

```
<jhi-gestion-imputacion-detalle
  (volverEvent)="volverDetalle($event)"
  [childReportesParte]="parentReportesParte"
  [parentVerTabla]="childVerTabla"
  *ngIf="!parentVerTabla"
>
</jhi-gestion-imputacion-detalle>

....

 <tr (click)="detalle(parte)">
```

// controller father

```
ViewChild(GestionImputacionDetalleComponent) child: GestionImputacionDetalleComponent;

detalle(parte: GestionImputacionData) {
    this.parentVerTabla = false;
    this.parte = parte;
    this.child.cargar(this.parte); <-- child is undefined
}
```

The problem is that "child" is undefined. What I see in the forums is "AfterViewInit", but that's when the controller starts, not like I need, that the child component is painted by clicking on a row of my parent component table.

How can I do so by clicking on the row of my table, I paint the child component and I can call a function of it, when it is created.

Comment: You should use [hidden]="parentVerTabla" instead of *ngIf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `[hidden]` to hide the children component from the DOM.

`*ngIf` removes the child component from DOM so the `@viewChild()` won't work. but with the use of `[hidden]`, you only hides the element so `@viewChild()` will work.

```
<jhi-gestion-imputacion-detalle
  (volverEvent)="volverDetalle($event)"
  [childReportesParte]="parentReportesParte"
  [parentVerTabla]="childVerTabla"
  [hidden]="parentVerTabla"
>
```

- **[hidden]** - adds `display: none;` property to the element's style based on conditions.
- ***ngIf** - adds/removes the element from the DOM based on conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach is using a @Input in your children to pass the data and take account that, when children becomes visible, ngOnInit of the children is called

```
//children
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit  {
  @Input() name: string;
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.name=this.name+" updated"
  }
}
```

.

```
//parent
<hello *ngIf="childVisible" name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<button (click)="childVisible=!childVisible">click</button>
```

[stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvhcdm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)